# Saving binary numbers from char type into an array to use them later

Tags: c, arrays, binary, char, scanf

I have to do a homework. Following task:

First you are asked, how many binary numbers you want to type - you can only type between 1 to 5 binaries, everything else will cause an error.
The input is a binary number (e.g. 01011011) which must consist of 8 digits (so 1010 or 1000010000 would be false).
After entering the 8 digits binary number, we have to save the typed in binary number from the user.

My Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main () {

char c,input[8];
int s2,amount,y=0,s3;
int s=0,i[s];

printf("How many binary numbers? ");
scanf("%i",&amount);

while(amount < 1||amount > 5) {
  printf("F A I L U R E\n");        
  printf("How many binary numbers? ");
  scanf("%i",&amount);
  if(amount >= 1 && amount<=5) {
  break;
  }
}

for(s3=1;s3<=amount;s3++){
    L0:
    printf("Please enter binary Number (8 digits): ");
        for(s2=0;s2<=8;s2++) {
        c = getche();
            if(c=='0'||c=='1') {
                y=1;}
            else
                y=0;

        if(y==1) { 

            if(s2==7) {
                input[s2]=c;
                input[8]='\0';
            break;}

            else
                input[s2]=c;}

        else if(y==0) {
            break;}
}

if(y==0) {
    input[0]='\0';
    printf("\n");
    printf("F A I L U R E: Incorrect Input\n");    
    goto L0;
    }
else
    //Now save the binary numbers in a variable
    //Tried:

    sscanf(input,"%i",&i[s]);
    printf("\nBinary number is saved: %i\n\n",i[s]);
    s++;
    //Problem: if 000100100 --> makes do Octal because of leading 0
    //for example if input is 01110011 -> Output is:
    //if there is no leading 0, it works
}
//Just for testing, if it was rly saved - two inputs.. - works
printf("The first saved binary was: %i\n",i[0]);
printf("The second saved binary was: %i\n",i[1]);

}
```

I used the `sscanf()` function to save the input and it works, but not if the number has a leading zero (e.g. 01101100 turns to 295488) - this is because C interprets numbers with a leading 0 as octal. So I don't know how I can get rid of this problem. I left a picture of the terminal output to show you the problem.[Image-Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9sIg.png))

Would anyone have an idea how can I save the written binary number into an array variable without getting an octal number? Or is there another way without `sscanf()`?

Comment: Used sscanf(input,"%d",&i[s]); instead of sscanf(input,"%i",&i[s]);

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH! it works now :)